# php is the constructor called when each method is called?

Tags: php

Is the __construct method called every time you run a method in a class? Example:

```
class SomeClass {
    function __construct() {
      // do something
    }

    function a() {
       // do something for a
    }
}
```

So when I call the class

```
$class = new SomeClass();
```

I believe the constructor is run? But how about when I do something like the following:

```
echo $class->a();
```

Is the constructor run again at this point?

Comment: I don't have access to a development environment on this PC and its something I thought about whilst doing some reading and couldn't find a clear answer on it, new to OOP sorry.

Comment: @twigg http://eval.in http://codepad.org & so many more...

Comment: thanks @HD im only a hobbyist coder, if I don't ask then I will never know will I

Comment: @twigg: There's nothing to be sorry about. I was simply suggesting a much more efficient way of getting answers to this type of question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.** As stated [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

> Classes which have a constructor method call this method on **each
>   newly-created object**, so it is suitable for any initialization that
>   the object may need **before it is used**.

In the end, constructors implicitly called only when you creating object. So in your example:

```
$class = new SomeClass();
//       ^ triggers constructor
echo $class->a()
//       ^ not triggering constructor but have to be initialized before usage
```

Answer (score 3):

As the name "constructor" should suggest, it is only implicitly called when the object instance if created, not for each method call, so the answer here is **NO**.

You can find the related docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

As Clément Malet suggests, you could always call it yourself by adding `$this->__construct();` in any of your methods!

If you wish to call a method of a class without creating an instance, it must be a `static` method, see http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: how someone call class method without it's instance?

Comment: @diEcho static methods?

Comment: Saying that it is **only** called when it is instantiated is half true though

Comment: static methods does not called using `->` at all

Comment: I know. But you're still calling a method that is defined within `class foo {}`

Comment: @ClémentMalet true, I guess you could use reflection to obtain an instance without calling the constructor. Or were you referring to something else?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I was just referring to the fact that you could call the constructor again by yourself, anyhow with, i.e `$this->__construct();`. See how @HAL9000 added the word 'implicitly' in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **no**. The constructor method automatically called on class instantiate.

See this example:

```
<?php

Class Test{

    public function __construct(){
        echo "Construct called" . PHP_EOL;
    }
        
    public function a_method(){
        echo "Running Method" . PHP_EOL;
    }
        
}

$a = new Test();
$a->a_method();
```

Output:

> Construct called
>
> Running Method

More info in [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Answer (score 1):

***No***, the constructor method won't be called again (on a method call).

For example, we have the following code;

```
<?php

class foo {

 public function __construct() {
     echo "Construct has been called". PHP_EOL;
 }
 
 public function a() {
     echo "a has been called" . PHP_EOL;
 }
 
}

//Now we have echo's within each method, when called, something will output.

$objFoo = new foo();

$objFoo->a();
```

- We have 2 methods `__construct()` and `a()`.

  - Both will echo output once called.
- We have 2 calls

  - One to instantiate the class
  - One to call `a()`

When we [run the code](https://eval.in/186468), we get the following output;

> Construct has been called
>
> a has been called

We have 2 separate calls, explicitly `__construct()` and `a()`, and only 2 lines of output - both expected, and nothing more is expected as `__construct()` was only called once - `new foo()`.

Have a look at the documentation;

- [__construct()](https://www.php.net/__construct)
- [Object orientated programming](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)